# Excel 'Runtime Error 424: Object required' when trying to create Autofit loop

Tags: excel, vba, module, range, subroutine

I'm really new to VBA in Excel, and I'm trying to use the following code in a module to go through each Worksheet and Autofit any cells that have Text Wrapping enabled:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop2()

     Dim Current As Worksheet

     For Each Current In Worksheets
        Call AutofitRows

     Next

End Sub

Sub AutofitRows()
    Dim CL As Range

    For Each CL In UsedRange
        If CL.WrapText Then CL.Rows.AutoFit
    Next
End Sub
```

However when I try to run this, it pops up an 'Error 424: Object required' box, and then the debugger highlights the line:

```
For Each CL In UsedRange
```

If I put the AutofitRows code into a specific Worksheet and then run it, it works fine, but I want to run the Macro over around 25 Worksheets in one go rather than having to do them individually.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm obviously missing something completely obvious, but I can't wrap my head around why it doesn't work.

Comment: Change to `Sub AutofitRows(ByVal ws as Worksheet)`, then change `UsedRange` to `ws.UsedRange`, and change `Call AutofitRows` to `AutofitRows Current`.

Comment: The `UsedRange` is a property of a `Worksheet`... you need to specify the worksheet and you can by passing it as a parameter.